# Display query results in new form after selecting item in listbox

Tags: c#, sql, visual-studio-2010, ms-access

I have 2 forms: `RoomSelect` and `RoomActiveSessions`.

`RoomSelect` form contains of listbox (listbox1) and a button (button1). The listbox is binded to a local database table called "`Room`" and displays 4 different room numbers.

Room table

```
(PK)RoomID RoomName
CMP2001      room 1
MB20312      room 2
FR45312      room 3
TRY2233      room 4
```

RoomID is used as a foreign key in aother table, `Sessions`

```
(PK)sessionID (FK)roomID sessionStartDate sessionTimeStart sessionTimeEnd
1ACMP2343       CMP2001     09/05/2013          12:00 AM         14:00 PM
2ACMP2343       MB20312     05/05/2013          09:00 AM         11:00 PM
1ACMP3456       TRY2233     15/05/2013          12:00 AM         13:00 PM
2ACMP3456       CMP2001     01/05/2013          10:00 AM         13:00 PM
1ABIO3422       MB20312     30/04/2013          11:00 AM         13:00 PM
2ABIO3422       CMP2001     01/04/2013          14:00 AM         16:00 PM
1ABIO2217       FR45312     12/05/2013          16:00 AM         18:00 PM
2ABIO2217       MB20312     03/05/2013          12:00 AM         14:00 PM
```

`RoomActiveSession` form contains of dataGridView where I would like to display my results.

The process should look like this:

1. User start application on the form `RoomSelect`.
2. User selects the room number and click OK.
3. `RoomSelect` form closes and `RoomActiveSession` opens with the current sessions displayed for the given room number

I presume that to achieve this I need to use the value from the listbox as a parameter when running a query on a database, but I dont know how to access it. When I try to get it with:

```
private void listBox1_SelectedIndexChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {

            MessageBox.Show(listBox1.SelectedItem.ToString());
        }
```

I get System.Data.RowView, not the value from the DB.

I would appreciate some help with my problem

EDIT:

One more question. How can I open a new form after highlighting room number and clicking OK on `RoomSelect` form?

Answer (score 0):

If it's a `DataRowView` that you're getting, then do this:

```
if (listBox1.SelectedItem is DataRowView)
{
    DataRowView drv = (DataRowView)listBox1.SelectedItem;
    String s = drv["RoomID"] as String;
    if (!String.IsNullOrEmpty(s))
        MessageBox.Show(s);
}
```

A bit verbose for your goal, perhaps, but just for demonstration of what is really in that `SelectedItem` property.